# Gitlab задание проходит успешно, но minio cache не обновляет

Tags: gitlab-ci, minio

Доброго времени суток!

Есть странная проблема, описано gitlab задание на обновление кеша, в качестве хранения кеша используется minio. На minio закончилось место и при попытке записать в него данные он выдает ошибку, однако gitlab задание при этом проходит успешно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
dependencies:
  stage: dependencies
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: "development"
  script:
    - yarn install --prefer-offline --frozen-lockfile
```

Как можно это устранить?